# How to report progress to all clients using MVC and self host signalr

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am very new to SignalR. 
I am trying to create a simulated conveyor that many clients can view the position of the conveyor (the simulated conveyor is a jQuery ui progressbar).

What I have (and posted below) works across many clients - but the more clients you open, the faster the conveyor runs.  it almost seems that each push to the client in turn posts back to the server and so on.

My question is how can I have multiple clients viewing this simulated conveyor and not have the conveyor increment faster base on number of clients viewing it?

Hub code

```
 public class ConveyorHub : Hub
{
    public static  int ConveyorPosition { get; set; }
    private Timer _timer;
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Initialize();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        ConveyorPosition = 0;
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => Clients.All.reportConveyorMovement(ConveyorPosition++);
            _timer.Start();
        } 
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="progress-container">
<label class="progress-name">Simulated Conveyor</label>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/hubs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var progressbar = $("#progressbar");
        var progressLabel = $(".progress-label");

        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
        var conveyorHub = $.connection.ConveyorHub;

        conveyorHub.client.reportConveyorMovement = function(val) {
            progress(val);
        };

        progressbar.progressbar({ value: 0 });

        function progress(val) {
            var progressbarValue = progressbar.find(".ui-progressbar-value");
            if (val >= 75 && val < 99) {
                progressbarValue.css({
                    "background": 'yellow'
                });
            }
            if (val >= 99) {
                progressbarValue.css({
                    "background": 'red'
                });
            }
            progressbar.progressbar("value", val);
            progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
        }

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function() {
                $("#progressbar").change(function() {

                });
            }).fail(function() { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
_timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => Clients.All.reportConveyorMovement(ConveyorPosition++);
```

Try this instead, the problem is that you are telling for each client to increment the conveyor position.  In this way you increment precisely once:

```
_timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
       ++ConveyorPosition;
       Clients.All.reportConveyorMovement(ConveyorPosition);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still speeds up when more clients are added.  Also with that change, all clients reset to 0% when a new client is opened

Comment: Oh sorry, does more than one hub get created? I suspect so.  That would make multiple timers, because the ConveyorPosition is static.  Which would increase as dudes get added.

Comment: thank you. you gave me an idea.  Since the timer is created in the initialize and that is called from the OnConnected, a new timer gets created for every client that gets connected. I put a stop in the initialize and that is exactly what it is doing.
Now how can I get multiple hubs to see only one timer? I made the timer static and it worked.  thanks again